# Read/set botstate using NodeJS SDK

Tags: botframework

There is a REST API for read/set botstate: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/state/#!/BotState/BotState_SetUserData
I'm wondering if I can user NodeJS SDK to interact with botstate through that API (but without dealing with authentication and raw API calls handling)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interact with the bot's state via:

- `session.userData`
- `session.dialogData`
- `session.conversationData`
- `session.privateConversationData`
- `session.save()`

btw, the active dialog stack is persisted on the `privateConversationData`. Fun fact.

I recently did some explorations around state persistence so this blog post of mine might come in handy: http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-4-transcript/

Comment: Pavel, thanks for the answer. Looks like those `session` properties read/set data from/to a different source (rather than while using REST API). I tried both approaches and only using Bot State API is reliable across platforms/time (basically I'm putting data to the bot's state from my webservice and then read it with bot, again through API, whenever I need it in the real conversation with a user).

Comment: `ChatConnector` uses `https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/`. Look at `getData()` and `setData()` in there. It won't use that store for when you run in the emulator or if you are using the `ConsoleConnector`.

Comment: Pavel, I've read you article more thoroughly - great example and explanations. And it fully covers/answers my question. Thanks.